# Set authentication rule in Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

To simplify understanding, I'll simplify my Firebase structure.

```
Users/uid/randonUidClub

Clubs/randonUid/users/uidUsers
```

I need to grant read and write access to `Clubs` only for authenticated `Users` and that their UIDs are within `users/uidUsers`.

Can anyone help me to set this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "clubs": {
      "$clubId": {
        ".read": "auth != null && data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this rule you can only read a club (`/clubs/{clubId}`) if you are authenticated and if the current user UID exists in `/clubs/{clubId}/users`

Works with the following sample data:

```
+ clubs
  + 1
    + users
      + 02a13901-f145-4ac6-870d-9f91e5eed7ed
        + id: "02a13901-f145-4ac6-870d-9f91e5eed7ed"
```

Comment: Thanks... I'll test it later and check it

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: Nice! Have a nice day.